# javascript .replace only when specific string appears

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to correct a grammar error from an API. I'm attempting to replace `70,2bn` to `70.2bn` I've went about it to just simply to `.replace(/,[0-9]bn/g, '.')` but this ends up removing the last number after the comma.

Here is an example of the full string  `"The average population is 492,213 and revenue generated is 70,2bn"`

With the current `.replace(/,[0-9]bn/g, '.')` it is replacing the comma with a period which I am expecting, but how can I return back the number that is cut off?

This number `70,2bn` is different per page, so I attempting to find a solution that will work for different scenarios that include `bn` such as `2,1bn, 100,3bn` etc.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
let string = "The average population is 492,213 and revenue generated is 70,2bn"
console.log(string)


string = string.replace(/,[0-9]bn/g, '.bn')
console.log(string)
```

I am expecting an outcome of `"The average population is 492,213 and revenue generated is 70.2bn"`

Comment: `string.replace(/,([0-9]bn)/g, '.$1')`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
> '70,2bn'.replace(/(\d+),(\d+bn\b)/g, '$1.$2')
"70.2bn"
```